# Angular 1.6.1 ng--option values prefixed with type:

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

This problem is driving me crazy. I am trying to pre-select a value using ng-options as follows:

```
<select name="listing_type_id" ng-model="listing_type_id" 
        ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in listingTypes">
</select>
```

This work but my value in the generated drop-down are prefixed with "number:" - for some reason which is baffling.

I know that this doesn't happen in earlier version of Angular 1.x. I am using 1.6.1 which is affected by this annoyance.

I have done some reading and people suggest to use "track by i.id" in the ng-options directive, this did remove the type prefix as desired but also killed my pre-selected item. I also read that I should not care about how the value is rendered in the value field as i should be using the $scope to read the selected item. In my case I am not submitting my form via angular, I'm just using angular for some validation.

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qhg63w2f/

Comment: The Fiddle doesn't use `ng-options`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please pre defile your values in controller what you selected.
```

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  /* Pre defile values if you are not seleted than blank pass*/
 $scope.myDropDown = 'two';
  
  /* ng-options values pre define */
  $scope.names = ["one", "two", "three"];
  
  $scope.listing_type_id = 3;
  $scope.listingTypes = [
    {"id" : 1, "name" : "one"}, 
    {"id" : 2, "name" : "two"}, 
    {"id" : 3, "name" : "three"}
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController as $ctrl">
  <div>
    Simple select dropdown : 
    <select ng-model="myDropDown">
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
      <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- ng-option to set values from controller and pre define selected values -->
  <div>
    ng-option : 
    <select ng-model="myDropDown" ng-options="item for item in names"></select>
  </div>
  
  <div ng-if="myDropDown == 'two' || myDropDown == 'three'">
    <!-- Will be displayed only when you select 'two' or 'three' -->  
    <input type="text" ng-model="fname" />
  </div>

  <div>
    Your Code ng-option : 
    <select name="listing_type_id" ng-model="listing_type_id" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in listingTypes"></select>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see anything different in your solution, the values are rendered as "string:..." and "number:...."